# javascript execution on different browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, brave

on click of "click me" button in below code I have observed different behaviour on Firefox and Brave/Chrome.
Below is the behaviour for each browser, when "click me" button is clicked:

1. Firefox: hidden text is shown and then the confirm box pops-up.
2. Brave/Chrome: confirm box pops-up and after responding (clicking ok or cancel) to confirm box the hidden text shows up.

My question is that since the code to show the hidden text comes prior to confirm-box code, Why does this behave as it does in Brave/Chrome?

Shouldn't the hidden text show up prior to confirm-box always in all browsers?
or am I missing something?

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>js execution test</title>

        <style>
            #some-text {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="some-text">some text here to read</div>

        <button type="button" onclick="invokeMe()">click me</button>

        <script>
            function invokeMe() {
                let someText = document.getElementById("some-text");

                someText.style.display = "block";
                someText.style.fontSize = "3em";

                confirm("doesn't matter if you choose ok or cancel");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: All happens when the repaints happen

Comment: I want the behaviour to be as Firefox does it. Can I force Brave to do so?
Also please refer to any online resources regarding the 'repaint' that the browsers does

Comment: delay the confirm with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame ?